# Does anyone else have a Flurry crash CalledFromWrongThreadException?

Tags: android, flurry, mopub

I use Flurry through MoPub. I use the MoPub provided adapters for Flurry, so essentially I have zero code of my own for Flurry. 
I keep getting these crashes from them on Crashlytics, basically, they are all `CalledFromWrongThreadException`. 
I've never reproduced the issue myself. Flurry claims it must be my code but like I said, I have zero Flurry specific code and I don't get that crash with any other ad network. The stack trace shows it is all within Flurry's code. It isn't clear from the stacktrace whether this is a interstitial crash or a native ad crash.

Is anyone else seeing crashes like this?

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7901)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1322)
       at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:21049)
       at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:21049)
       at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:21049)
       at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:21049)
       at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:21049)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:360)
       at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:21049)
       at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:8621)
       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5131)
       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4956)
       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4931)
       at com.flurry.sdk.hq$2.run(SourceFile:123)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: Are you, by chance, just creating objects from Flurry? Whether they are being used is a different scenario.

Comment: Nope, my actual code has zero calls to Flurry, it is all MoPub calling Flurry when it reaches that point on the waterfall.

Comment: is it possible to post the actual/sample code?